# Is the relation c=νλ valid only for Electromagnetic waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wave-particle-duality

What is the validity of the relation $c = \nu\lambda$?
More specifically, is this equation valid **only** for Electromagnetic waves?

I read this statement in a book, which says:

> de Broglie waves are not electromagnetic in nature, because they do not arise out of accelerated charged particle.

This seems correct, but arises a doubt in my mind. 
Suppose I find out the wavelength of a matter wave (or de Broglie wave) using de Broglie's wave equation: $$\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$$

Now, can I use $c = \nu\lambda$ to find out the frequency of the wave?

Comment: No, now you cannot use $c= \nu\lambda$

Comment: It would be $v=\nu\lambda$ where v is speed of matter wave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The general relation is given by

$$v = \lambda\nu$$

Where $v$ is the velocity of the considered wave and $\lambda$ and $\nu$ its wavelength and frequency. Of course in the case of an electromagnetic wave which is traveling at the speed of light you gain

$$c = \lambda\nu$$

If you're treating instead some massive particle, then thou have $$p = \frac{Ev}{c^2}$$

and using $E = \frac{h}{\nu}$ you obtain $$p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$$

For a **non-relativistic** particle

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{p} = \frac{h}{\sqrt{2mK}}$$, where $K$ is the non-relativistic kinetic energy $K = \frac{p^2}{2m}$.